# Can't get market data by iterating through list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to add a column to a df that has the market caps of the tickers in the code column. I keep getting thrown an error and don't understand where I went wrong. I am able to show that the method of getting the market cap from an australian market ticker works (# instance of getting mc that works #) but can't seem to iterate this through the list i made.

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import csv
import yfinance
from pandas_datareader import data

######## SCRAPING DIRECTOR TRADES #########
req = Request('https://smallcaps.com.au/director-transactions/'
              , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
trades = urlopen(req).read()

######## CLEANING DATA #########
df = pd.read_html(trades)[0]
del df['Director'],df['Company']
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '')\
    .str.replace('↑', '').str.replace('↓', '-')
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int)
print(df)
####### Instance of getting market cap that works ########
print(data.get_quote_yahoo('LKE.AX')['marketCap'])

######## New market cap column ########
df['Code']=df['Code'] + ".AX" #accounting for australian market by adding .AX

MC=[]
for code in df['Code']:
    MC.append(data.get_quote_yahoo(code)['marketCap'])

df['Market Cap']=MC #Add MC list as a new column to dataframe
print(df)
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Scraper/DirectorTrades.py
           Date Code     Value
0     29/4/2022  CTQ    102306
1     29/4/2022  SUH    435000
2     29/4/2022  WAM -17656948
3     28/4/2022  MXI     10297
4     28/4/2022  FGX     10804
...         ...  ...       ...
3742  23/8/2021  SFC    204229
3743  23/8/2021  WWI      8040
3744  23/8/2021  AX1     47972
3745  23/8/2021  BSA     28750
3746  23/8/2021  SGR    180500

[3747 rows x 3 columns]
    enter code here
LKE.AX    2530701568
Name: marketCap, dtype: int64

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraper\DirectorTrades.py", line 26, in <module>
    MC.append(data.get_quote_yahoo(code)['marketCap'])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 96, in get_quote_yahoo
    return YahooQuotesReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\quotes.py", line 49, in read
    return self._read_one_data(self.url, self.params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 113, in _read_one_data
    return self._read_lines(out)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\quotes.py", line 66, in _read_lines
    data = json.loads(out.read())["quoteResponse"]["result"][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import seems to be wrong.

Instead of `from pandas_datareader import data`, try using `import pandas_datareader as data`

Comment: I tried that but got the same error. The original should be fine since it works with the LKE.AX example.

Comment: Maybe try updating your packages. I tried the same code you attached above and its working for me.